# Qt tableWidget cells color

Tags: c++, qt, colors, widget, cell

I got stuck on trying to set background color in Qt tableWidget. I very hope for your help.
Here is my code.

```
QColor colorLive( Qt::red );
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(14);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(14);
for (int g = 0; g < 15; ++g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setItem( g, i, new QTableWidgetItem );
        ui->tableWidget->item( g, i )->setBackgroundColor( colorLive );
        // error here
    }
}
```

Application output shows next: `The program has unexpectedly finished.`
But if i change error line of code by 
`ui->tableWidget->item( 0, 0 )->setBackgroundColor( colorLive );`
,then it works for one cell. But, actually, I need to set all cells, or part of them. I will be very grateful if you help me!

Comment: okey, I found it out. It works if make this way:
int g = 0;

         while(g != 14){
           int i = 0;
             while(i != 14){
            QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem(tr("%1").arg(""));
            ui->tableWidget->setItem( g, i, newItem );
            ui->tableWidget->item( g, i )->setBackgroundColor( colorDeath );
            //
            ++i;
        }
             ++g;
        }

Answer (score 0):

You are going beyond your column and row count. You set `columnCount` and `rowCount` to 14. This means the valid range is 0-13. But in your for loop you are going through rows 0-14 and columns 0-14. Row 14 and columns 14 are not valid.

This should fix it:

```
int rows = 14;
int columns = 14;
QColor colorLive(Qt::red);
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(rows);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(columns);
for (int g = 0; g < rows; ++g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
    {
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(g, i, new QTableWidgetItem);
        ui->tableWidget->item(g, i)->setBackgroundColor(colorLive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh, god thanks, I assumed it is the same as an array. that is why I placed the size 14. Thank you!

Comment: @undermorrk But an array would behave the same way :o. `int array[14];` would also have 14 elements in the range of 0-13. But anyway, if the answer solved your problem, you should accept it :)